# Questions about Craft 4 release and licenses

Tags: license, upgrades, craft4

Being busy rethinking an existing website to rebuild in Craft I just found out Craft 4 was announced september last year. Some of the new features, like nestable Matrix fields in particular, are very welcome and chances are I'd rather wait for Craft 4 to come out to convert a big amount of data to the new CMS than to rebuild the website in Craft 3 to have another data-migration(/rebuild?) for new fields etc. in Craft 4 later.

So I'm having the following questions:

1) Is there anything to say about a release date for Craft 4? And about around what time Pixel and Tonic consider it a stable release to be used in production?

2) What will happen to the support and updates for Craft 3 once Craft 4 is out? Is there any roadmap showing support/update-cycles for Pixel and Tonic products?

3) Will Craft 3 work with the announced Craft Cloud or will the cloud only work from version 4 up?

4) Is there anything to say about how difficult it will likely be to migrate from v3 to v4 and what that would be about?

5) What about existing paid licenses when a customer upgrades from version 3 to 4? Is it under the same license after the upgrade? Or are licenses bound to a major version and need a customer buy a new license for version 4?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Is there anything to say about a release date for Craft 4? And about around what time Pixel and Tonic consider it a stable release to be used in production?

Nothing official on either.

> 2) What will happen to the support and updates for Craft 3 once Craft 4 is out? Is there any roadmap showing support/update-cycles for Pixel and Tonic products?

No official dates yet, but you can probably use past support timelines (https://craftcms.com/guides/supported-versions) as a guide to what Craft 3 support would be once Craft 4 is out.

> 3) Will Craft 3 work with the announced Craft Cloud or will the cloud only work from version 4 up?

Nothing officially announced.

> 4) Is there anything to say about how difficult it will likely be to migrate from v3 to v4 and what that would be about?

We'll try to make the 3 => 4 migration as seamless as possible.

> 5) What about existing paid licenses when a customer upgrades from version 3 to 4? Is it under the same license after the upgrade? Or are licenses bound to a major version and need a customer buy a new license for version 4?

The licensing model should be exactly how it is for Craft 3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and link to the support timelines @Brad Bell. I was hoping you could tell something about around what about time a release would be expected, but I understand you don't want to make promises and it's probably too early for that. So that's also an answer to my question. I'll probably stick with Craft 3 for now than as otherwise it would be a long wait, and upgrade/migrate to 4 later. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Craft 4 will be released in Q1 2022 with a stable release coming in Q2.

https://craftquest.io/dotall#state-of-craft